# AzureSynapse pipeline how to add guid to raw data

Tags: sql-server, import, azure-pipelines, uniqueidentifier, azure-synapse

I am new to AzureSynapse and am technically a Data Scientist whos doing a Data Engineering task. Please help!

I have some xlsx files containing raw data that I need to import into an SQL database table. The issue is that the raw data does not have a uniqueidentifer column and I need to add one before inserting the data into my SQL database.

I have been able to successfully add all the rows to the table by adding a new column on the Copy Data command and setting it to be @guid(). However, this sets the guid of every row to the same value (not unique for each row).

GUID mapping:
[image: @guid() mapping]

DB Result:
[image: DB results]

If I do not add this mapping, the pipeline throws an error stating that it cannot import a NULL Id into the column Id. Which makes sense as this column does not accept NULL values.

Is there a way to have AzureSynapse analystics read in a raw xlsx file and then import it into my DB with a unique identifier for each row? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Many many thanks for any support.

Comment: Our DB is MSSQL which I have added as a Linked Service as type 'SQL server'. Apologies if I misunderstand the question.

Comment: I am on MAC using Azure Data Studio to query and validate the Azure pipeline. The Database is a relational SQL database which I am attempting to add rows to through the AzureSynapse 'Copy data' activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Giving dynamic content to a column in this way would generate the same value for entire column.
- Instead, you can generate a new `guid` for each row using a `for each` activity.
- You can retrieve the data from your source excel file using a `lookup` activity (my source only has `name` column). Give the output array of lookup activity to `for each` activity.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

[image]

- Inside `for each`, since you already have a linked service, create a script activity. In this script activity, you can create a query with dynamic content to insert values into the destination table. The following is the query I built using dynamic content.

```
insert into demo values ('@{guid()}','@{item().name}')
```

[image]

- This allows you to iterate through source rows, insert each row individually while **generating new guid every time**

You can follow the above procedure to build a query to insert each row with unique identifier value. The following is an image where I used copy data to insert first 2 rows (same as yours) and inserted the next 2 rows using the above procedure.

[image]

**NOTE:** I have taken Azure SQL database for demo, but that does not affect the procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Saideep. It does appear to be working and adding rows with unique id's. However, the problem now is that the foreign text is displaying as ???????. The DB columns are set to nvarchar and can accept foreign text. Is this an issue with the lookup configuration?

When using the Copy Data activity, the foreign text was displaying correctly, but I was not able to get unique ids. Now I have unique ids but the foreign text is not displaying.

Comment: I can request this data in either parquet or json format if this will help at all. It is currently in xlsx. I have tried .csv, but there are commas in some of the fields and it appears that AzureSynapse is not as clever at handling commas in the fields as pandas is

Comment: I have checked and the foreign text has been identified properly by look up. Try checking the debug output of your lookup if foreign text is recognized. [This image](https://i.imgur.com/IUUhLWg.png) shows my debug output where lookup recognizes foreign text when source is a JSON.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the output and it indeed does detect the foreign text. The issue does seem to be with the ForEach import command. I will post another question. Thank you very much for your help Saideep.